# Cocos2d-x cannot run build-win32.bat on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: batch-file, cocos2d-x

I'm new in cocos2d-x. I started setting up environment for developing. 
I download the cocos2d-x-2.1.5 zip file and extracted. Then I double click on build-win32.bat, these line apppeared :

```
Build started 8/28/2013 9:08:01 AM.
 0>D:\Dev_cocos2dx\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln : Solution file error      MSB5009: Erro
   r parsing the nested project section in solution file.

Build FAILED.

     D:\Dev_cocos2dx\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln : Solution file error MSB5009: Er
   ror parsing the nested project section in solution file.

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18052]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 8/28/2013 9:08:01 AM.
 0>D:\Dev_cocos2dx\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln : Solution file error     MSB5009: Erro
   r parsing the nested project section in solution file.

Build FAILED.

     D:\Dev_cocos2dx\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln : Solution file error MSB5009: Er
   ror parsing the nested project section in solution file.

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01
/*
* Check the cocos2d-win32 application "TestCpp.exe" ...
*/

The system cannot find the path specified.
/*
* Run cocos2d-win32 tests.exe and view Cocos2d-x Application Wizard for Visual Studio  User Guide.
*/

File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - js
0 File(s) copied
File not found - tests
0 File(s) copied
File not found - MoonWarriors
0 File(s) copied
File not found - WatermelonWithMe
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Published files iOS
0 File(s) copied
Can't find the binary "TestCpp.exe", is there build error?
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm using windows 7 64bit . 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1.Open the "cocos2d-win32.vc2010.sln".

2.Create a new project.

3.Delete the project of step 2.

4.Close .sln file, click save.

After these steps, my batch file works well. Hope it is useful for you.